# Keras learning rate decay in pytorch

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have a question concerning learning rate decay in Keras. I need to understand how the option decay works inside optimizers in order to translate it to an equivalent PyTorch formulation.

From the source code of SGD I see that the update is done this way after every batch update:

```
lr = self.lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * self.iterations))
```

Does this mean that after every batch update the lr is updated starting from its value from its previous update or from its initial value? I mean, which of the two following interpretation is the correct one?

```
lr = lr_0 * (1. / (1. + self.decay * self.iterations))
```

or

`lr = lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * self.iterations))`,

where `lr` is the lr updated after previous iteration and `lr_0` is always the initial learning rate.

If the correct answer is the first one, this would mean that, in my case, the learning rate would decay from 0.001 to just 0.0002 after 100 epochs, whereas in the second case it would decay from 0.001 at around 1e-230 after 70 epochs.

Just to give you some context, I'm working with a CNN for a regression problem from images and I just have to translate Keras code into Pytorch code. So far, with the second of the afore-mentioned interpretations I manage to only always predict the same value, disregarding of batch size and input at test time.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the implementation in [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2f55055a9f053b35fa721d3eb75dd07ea5a5f1e3/keras/optimizers.py#L189) I think your first formulation is the correct one, the one that contain the initial learning rate (note that `self.lr` is not being updated).

However I think your calculation is probably not correct: since the denominator is the same, and `lr_0` >= `lr` since you are doing decay, the first formulation has to result in a bigger number.

I'm not sure if this decay is available in PyTorch, but you can easily create something similar with `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR`.

```
decay = .001
fcn = lambda step: 1./(1. + decay*step)
scheduler = LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=fcn)
```

Finally, don't forget that you will need to call `.step()` explicitly on the scheduler, it's not enough to step your optimizer. Also, most often learning scheduling is only done after a full epoch, not after every single batch, but I see that here you are just recreating Keras behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much @mkisantal. I must have switched the two calculations, you are right when you say that the first formulation should result in a bigger number. I will edit my question to correct it, but your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the response of [mkisantal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55664538) might be incorrect, since the actual equation for the learning rate in keras (at least it was, now there is no default decay option) was like this:

```
lr = lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * self.iterations))
```

(see https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.0/keras/optimizers.py#L178)

And the solution presented by mkisantal is missing the recurrent/multiplicative term `lr`, therefore the more accurate version should be based on [**MultiplicativeLR**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiplicativeLR):

```
decay = .001
fcn = lambda step: 1./(1. + decay*step)
scheduler = MultiplicativeLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=fcn)
```